# How to write in a specific location the zapfdingbatslist in a pdf document using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I want to put a check mark using **zapfdingbatslist** on my pdf document in *iTextSharp* in a **specific location**.

What I could do so far is I could show the check mark but it's all on the side of the document and not on a specific X, Y coordinate that I want it to be. I have a code below that would hopefully give you the idea of what I am talking about.

```
    String outputFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "Test.pdf");
    System.IO.FileStream fs;
    Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 20, 20, 10, 10);
    PdfContentByte cb;
    PdfWriter writer;

    fs = new System.IO.FileStream(outputFile, System.IO.FileMode.Create);
    writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs);
    doc.SetPageSize(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4.Rotate());
    writer.AddViewerPreference(PdfName.PICKTRAYBYPDFSIZE, PdfBoolean.PDFTRUE);

    doc.Open();
    cb = writer.DirectContent;

    List myList = new ZapfDingbatsList(52); // Check mark symbol from Dingbatslist

    // I have some more code here but it is not needed for the problem
    // and thererfore not shown


    // I could shohw the dingbatslist check mark here
    myList.Add(" ");
    doc.Add(myList); // However I want to show it in a specific X, Y position

    doc.Close();
    writer.Close();
    fs.Close();
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Incidentally, I'm the author of most of the [iText documentation](http://itextpdf.com/book/) (as well as the original developer of iText, including the `Document`, `PdfWriter`, `ZapfdingbatsList`,... classes), and I'd appreciate it if you took some time to read the iText documentation.

Let's start with [chapter 2](http://www.manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter2.pdf) and take a look at [some C# examples](http://tinyurl.com/iiacsCH02) that introduce the `Font` class.

For instance:

```
Font font = new Font(Font.FontFamily.ZAPFDINGBATS, 12);
```

Once you have a Font object, you can create a `Phrase` (also explained in chapter 2):

```
Phrase phrase = new Phrase(zapfstring, font);
```

Where `zapfstring` is a `string` containing any Zapfdingbats character you want.

To add this Phrase at an absolute position, you need to read chapter 3. Take a look at [the examples](http://tinyurl.com/iiacsCH03) for inspiration, for instance [FoobarFilmfestival.cs](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/book/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/Chapter03/FoobarFilmFestival.cs):

```
PdfContentByte canvas = writer.DirectContent;
ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(canvas, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, phrase, 200, 500, 0);
```

Where `200` and `500` are an X and Y coordinate and `0` is an angle expressed in degrees. Instead of `ALIGN_CENTER`, you can also choose `ALIGN_RIGHT` or `ALIGN_LEFT`.

In your code sample you were adding a Zapfdingbats glyph to a document using a list. Please take a moment to put yourself in my place. Doesn't that feel as if you're the inventor of the sock attending a Red Hot Chili Peppers' concert?

Comment: This is what I love here at SO you could pick up many brilliant minds. And how many people would get an answer directly from an author of a quality book? Not too many I guess. Thank you Mr @BrunoLowagie I definitely appreciate your correct response/solution. GOD bless.

Comment: Part of my work is answering questions, but being on SO is fun ;-)